# How do I set up Spring Security while deployed and working locally?

Tags: reactjs, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

**I want to have my API secure while deployed, but I run into CORS issues during local react development**
Currently, I'm permitting all origins, headers, and methods in Spring, so I can develop locally, but this is not secure enough for deployment.
The stack (Postgres, spring boot, react) will all be deployed and need security.
Is it possible to keep it secure while deployed and be able to develop the full stack locally without code change?  Or at least with minimal code change, like a boolean that runs it in dev mode or not, this security config vs that config?  Whatever best practice is.

Not as important, but I'm doing security in the depreciated  `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` way instead of component-based security configuration with lambda DSL.  However, I'm interested in the new way.  Again not as important.

Comment: Have you tried deploying your app? You are running into CORS issues because you are serving your react app on localhost:4200 or something during development, and your backend is running on localhost:8080 or something. A simple deployment would involve putting your static resources (react build) into classpath:static so you won't have CORS issues. You can try it locally, too. As for the how to change it, you can use a proxy in react or use conditional on property configuration in your springboot app.

Comment: The best practice is to use Spring profiles. You can have separate security configurations annotated with, say, `@Profile("dev")`/`@Profile("prod")` and run your app with appropriate profile active.

Comment: I haven't deployed this one.  But given past experience, I won't have CORS issues once deployed.  It's as you say.  Spring is on 8080 and react is on 3000, or something.  These are the types of answers I'm looking for.  The Spring profiles, local static, proxy, etc.  I'll look more into these.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to open the proxy！
The development environment uses webpack proxy, and the production environment uses nginx proxy.

Comment: I'll look into this, and a few other methods mentioned in the comments.  Thanks!